# Bitmap gets recycled for no apparent reason

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-bitmap

I have a problem with bitmap getting recycled without me calling the `recycle()` method, or having any problems with memory usage (to my knowledge at least, and i did check with device monitor etc).

Here is the relevant code:

First in my `onCreate()` i set the bitmap:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        ...

        mCurrentBitmap = MediaStorage.sCurrentBitmap;
        ...
```

Then i call the crop method, and set the mUndoBitmap which is the one i have a recycling problem with to a new bitmap created from mCurrentBitmap.

```
public void crop() {
        mUndoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);
        Log.d("bitmap", Boolean.toString(mUndoBitmap.isRecycled()));
        ...
        call crop activity here
        ...
}
```

Log returns that bitmap is NOT recycled.

Then i get the activity result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("bitmap", Boolean.toString(mUndoBitmap.isRecycled()));
                mCurrentBitmap = MediaStorage.sCurrentBitmap;
                mTouchImageView.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);
                ...
```

Still log returns that bitmap is not recycled.

Now, there is an undo button that does the following:

```
public void undo() {
        Log.d("bitmap", Boolean.toString(mUndoBitmap.isRecycled()));
        mRedoBitmap = mCurrentBitmap;
        mCurrentBitmap = mUndoBitmap;
        mTouchImageView.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);
        ...
```

Log return that bitmap is recycled and i get the "cant draw recycled bitmap" error.

Note that these three methods are called in succession and that nowhere in my code have i called recycle on any of the bitmaps. So, my question is this:
does anyone know why my bitmap gets recycled and how do i prevent it from happening?

Comment: when you call Bitmap.createBitmap Log.d in and out Bitmaps hash codes

Comment: Can you please be more concrete, when should i log hashes? Before Bitmap.createBitmap mUndoBitmap is null, so that would and does throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: no, after, Log.d in Bitmap hash and returned Bitmap hash

Comment: OK, im still now sure i understood exactly what you meant for me to log but i did the following: i logged the bitmap hash in `crop()`, `onActivityResult()`, and finally in the `undo()` method just before the statement which causes the error. Hashes were the same in all methods.

Comment: thats what i thought, try Bitmap.copy

Comment: What do the hashes mean? It seems to work with copy. What is the difference between Bitmap.copy and Bitmap.createBitmap?

Comment: in your case Bitmap.createBitmap works as: outBitmap = inBitmap so no copy is created